# Sending an ArrayList as a parameter in GWT-RPC

Tags: gwt, arraylist, rpc, gwt-rpc

I tried sending an ArrayList to an RPC service in GWT but keeps on failing.
Here is my code fragment

```
                greetingService.addNewQuestion(questionnaireKey, questionText, qcList, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>(){
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert("Something went wrong!\n"+caught.getMessage());

                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                    Window.alert("Question Added!");
                }

            });
```

QuestionChoice is a simple object with no method, and qcList is an ArrayList of QuestionChoice

```
public class QuestionChoice implements IsSerializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5668640935838672293L;
public String text;
public boolean isCorrect;

public QuestionChoice(){

}
public QuestionChoice(String text, boolean isCorrect){
    this.text = text;
    this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
}
```

}

Has anyone tried sending an ArrayList as a parameter in GWT-RPC?
If you do, please try to post your sample code here.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes.It is possible to send ArrayList in GWT Rpc.I think there is no fault in your code.Can you please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Can you post the signature of GreetingService's addNewQuestion?  And the error that you get (does it fail at compile-time or run-time?)

Comment: Hi guys, I guess the error is in my development environment. Maybe it was lack of project refresh, project clean-up, rebuild, GWT compile and app engine reload.

Yesterday after posting the question, I made a tweak using ArrayList<String> instead of ArrayList<QuestionChoice>.

This morning while loggin in back to stackoverflow(new user), as ImJasonH demanded the signature of "addNewQuestion" Method I realized that I had deformed my code so much so I had to rebuild it as it was, but to my surprised, it now worked! It sends the ArrayList<QuestionChoice> Object to the server. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Oh I apologized for my late reply, I thought stackoverflow will notify me by email. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to send an ArrayList as a parameter in GWT-RPC call. When developing the GWT-RPC code, a lot of times you may encounter errors when a request in GWT-RPC is invoked, this is due to a change in GWT-RPC service that may have not been corresponds to the clients compiled GWT-RPC definition. To solve this issue you have to restart your development server whenever you changed your codes in the server side classes, or in the GWT-RPC service defintion(ie GreetingService, GreetingServiceAsync and in GreetingServiceImpl)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GWT 1.5 and Java 1.6, the problem is the @Override annotation, you are not really overriding a method, you are implementing. Get rid of the annotation and everything should go fine.

Comment: At java 1.6 language level @Override annotation is allowed for implementing interface method also.ivanceras may use java 1.6 language level.

Comment: Ok, but GWT complains about it. When you use @Override on an implemented method it causes an error that shows up on the developer shell. Well, at least it happens with me.

Comment: Actually this problem just happens if you are using GWT 1.5 and Java 1.6. Sorry about that.